# Ideals in $B(H)$ are self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

It is known that every (closed two-sided) ideal in a $C^{*}$-algebra is self-adjoint. The proofs that I've seen involve functional calculus and approximate units. I am wondering whether there is a more direct approach in the particular case of $B(H)$ (for a Hilbert space $H$).

Comment: As you may be aware,  it actually holds that the only nonzero, proper, closed, 2-sided ideal $I \subset B(H)$ is the compact operators $K(H)$. In particular, $I$ is self-adjoint. This is more work to prove, however. Showing $K(H) \subset I$ is not hard, but I think showing $I \subset K(H)$ needs the spectral theorem or some similar tool.

Comment: @Mike I think all you need is this: If $A\in B(H)$ is non-compact, there is a a constant $a>0$ and an infinite dimensional subspace $V\subseteq H$ for which $\|Av\|\ge a\|v\|$ when $v\in V$. Let $C\colon H\to V$ be an isometry; then $AC$ has a left inverse $B$, i.e., $BAC=I$, and you're done. (Assuming $H$ is separable.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I agree with what you've written, but I don't see how to find $V$ directly. You can use that either $\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ or $\frac{A-A^*}{2i}$ is noncompact and apply the spectral theorem to the resulting noncompact self-adjoint... but you have something simpler in mind?

Comment: @Mike Maybe you're right, I didn't quite think it through. It's past my bedtime and my brain is turning to mush.

Comment: (Just for reference) The abstract and more sophisticated proof can be found at e.g. Corollary 1.17.3 p.43 in Sakai's book, C* and W* Algebras [https://books.google.de/books?id=2IhqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=1.17.3+Corollary+C*-Algebras+and+W*-Algebras+Sakai&source=bl&ots=Ms8s46fNvQ&sig=qDrrGOSkuVLCKC69EJcM1PCWZeo&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=bdmbVafME4HTsgHB77L4BQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=1.17.3%20Corollary%20C*-Algebras%20and%20W*-Algebras%20Sakai&f=false]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $T\in J$ where $J$ is a closed two-sided ideal in $B(H)$. Consider its polar decomposistion $T=U|T|$, where $|T|=(T^*T)^{1/2}$. Clearly $T^*T\in J$, so its square root $|T|$ is in $J$ too (granted, we use some small bit of functional calculus there). Therefore, $T^*=|T|U^*\in J$ as well.

**Edit:** As commented by Martin Argerami, this proof works for norm closed ideals in any von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Harald, maybe you should mention that your proof works for any norm-closed ideal of any von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Actually you don't need to suppose that $J$ is closed in the case of Hilbert spaces. For let $T\in J$, $T=U|T|$ be its polar decomposition. Then $|T|=U^*T$ (see, "MURPHY, C$^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory", p.51, theorem 2.3.4), so $|T|\in J$, without using functional calculus.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Of course! How could I have missed that? I must be getting rusty. Thanks for pointing it out.